# can image view resize itself according to the image it contains in iOS

Tags: ios, image, uiimageview

i have to add a number images to the view. the images i have from the designer are of correct size. it would speed up my work if i don't have to manually size each image-view as per size of the image and then select the image ( which anyways contains the right dimensions )

is there a way in which i can put an image-view of any size select image property and then select an option that would resize the image-view as per image

[image]

Comment: No, there is no way you can resize image view  acc. to the image size; however you can fit any image in an image view of a constant size but will have to compromise on its quality

Comment: This will possibly not work with your design, but anyway: You could try to place an imageview which is bigger than the image it should contain and place it at the appropriate position. When you select the mode 'center' the image will center in this view and keep it's dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

You can set their content mode to a position like center, left, right, top, bottom... That way the image will keep its original size.

You just need to make sure that the imageview is large enough to display the image, so it doesn't get cropped.

I don't know exactly what your designer provides you in terms of position of the elements, but it's probably the top left position, so use the Top Left mode so that the image within the imageview hugs the top left corner and keeps its original size.